# Post og.likes removes query string parameters

Tags: facebook-opengraph, jsapi

I am using FB.api to post a og.likes action, but I'd like to append tracking code to the URL, and Facebook removes the additional query string parameters, and the URL is the same as the HTML meta og:url parameter, plus additional Facebook parameters.

Is it possible to append parameters to this URL?

Comment: Have you found a solution ?